# By reference a pointer in C

Tags: pointers, struct, reference

```
void foo(structT* P){
   P = P->next;
   return;
}
void func(structT* P){
   foo(P);
   return 0;
}
```

In func(), it calls foo(P) which passes a pointer. And in foo(), the P get updated. Now, how do I get the updated value in func()? How do I use passing by reference in this case in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further judging whether this is a good idea for your real-world design (a `foo` function has by definition unspecified purpose; just note that mutating input params is often not a good idea), here is a quick solution.

You cannot in C. But you can pass a pointer to pointer:

```
void foo(structT** P){
   *P = (**P).next; // or "(*P)->next"
   return;
}
void func(structT* P){
   foo(&P);
   return 0;
}
```

---

Anecdote and warning from http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer:

> #### Three Star Programmer
>
> A rating system for C-programmers. The more indirect your pointers are (i.e. the more "*" before your variables), the higher your reputation will be. No-star C-programmers are virtually non-existent, as virtually all non-trivial programs require use of pointers. Most are one-star programmers. In the old times (well, I'm young, so these look like old times to me at least), one would occasionally find a piece of code done by a three-star programmer and shiver with awe.
>
> Some people even claimed they'd seen three-star code with function pointers involved, on more than one level of indirection. Sounded as real as UFOs to me.
>
> **Just to be clear: Being called a ThreeStarProgrammer is usually not a compliment.**

Comment: `typedef structT* structTptr; void foo(structTptr* P){}` Does this count for two stars?

Answer (score 1):

```
structT* foo(structT* P)
{
   if ( P != NULL )
       return P->next;
   else
       return NULL;
}

void func(structT* P){
   structT* P1 = foo(P);
}
```